# Replacing CDATA NavigableStrings with Tags in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup, cdata

I am parsing several XML document feeds with BeautifulSoup, and would like to do some preprocessing to replace non-standard `CDATA` tags with custom XML tags.  To illustrate:

The following XML source...

```
<title>The end of the world as we know it</title>
<category><![CDATA[Planking Dancing]]></category>
<pubDate><![CDATA[Sun, 16 Sep 2012 12:00:00 EDT]]></pubDate>
<dc:creator><![CDATA[Bart Simpson]]></dc:creator>
```

...would turn into:

```
<title>The end of the world as we know it</title>
<category><myTag>Planking Dancing<myTag></category>
<pubDate><myTag>Sun, 16 Sep 2012 12:00:00 EDT<myTag></pubDate>
<dc:creator><myTag>Bart Simpson<myTag></dc:creator>
```

I don't think this question has been asked before on SO (I tried a few different SO queries).  I've also tried a few different approaches using `.findAll('cdata', text=True)` and the applying the BeautifulSoup [`replaceWith()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Replacing%20one%20Element%20with%20Another) method to each resulting `NavigableString`.  The attempts I've made have resulted in either no substitution, or what looks like a recursive loop.

I'm happy to post my previous attempts, but given that the problem here is quite simple I'm hoping someone can post a clear example of how to accomplish the search-and-replace above using BeautifulSoup 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CData` is a subclass of `NavigableString`, so you can find all `CData`
elements by first searching for all `NavigableString` objects, and then testing
whether each is an instance of `CData`. Once you've got one, it's easily
replaced using `replaceWith`, as you suggested:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, CData, Tag
>>> source = """
... <title>The end of the world as we know it</title>
... <category><![CDATA[Planking Dancing]]></category>
... <pubDate><![CDATA[Sun, 16 Sep 2012 12:00:00 EDT]]></pubDate>
... <dc:creator><![CDATA[Bart Simpson]]></dc:creator>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
>>> for navstr in soup(text=True):
...     if isinstance(navstr, CData):
...         tag = Tag(soup, "myTag")
...         tag.insert(0, navstr[:])
...         navstr.replaceWith(tag)
... 
>>> soup

<title>The end of the world as we know it</title>
<category><myTag>Planking Dancing</myTag></category>
<pubdate><myTag>Sun, 16 Sep 2012 12:00:00 EDT</myTag></pubdate>
<dc:creator><myTag>Bart Simpson</myTag></dc:creator>

>>>
```

A couple of notes:

- you can call a `BeautifulSoup` object as though it were a function, and the
  effect is the same as calling its `.findAll()` method.
- The only way I know to get the content of a `CData` object in BS3 is to slice
  it, as in the snippet above. `str(navstr)` would keep all the
  `<![CDATA[...]]>` junk, which obviously you don't want. In BS4, `str(navstr)`
  gives you the content without the junk.